# redux-form-material-ui@4.3.3 requires a peer of material-ui@^0.19.0 || 1 but none is installed.

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm getting this error after npm install: redux-form-material-ui@4.3.3 requires a peer of material-ui@^0.19.0 || 1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory. That particular module has a `peerDependency`, that is - It requires another module to function properly but it does not require it directly.

You can read more about peerDependencies [here](http://npm.github.io/using-pkgs-docs/package-json/types/peerdependencies.html)

To solve your problem simply install the dependencies it indicates. In your case:

`npm install --save material-ui`

or, if you want version 1 (although it's still in beta and may not be suitable for production):

`npm install --save material-ui@next`

Answer (score 0):

You should do this: `$ npm i ajv`

Or you can do this: `$npm install -S ajv@^6.0.0`

It will work. I just have tried.